# background image rotator.php + jquery to show random photo every 4 sec

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

We all know the standard rotator php scripts that show a new photo each time the page is refreshed.

I have searched everywhere and don't know if its possible. 
I would like to set the background of a section like this:

background-image: url(https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/homeslider/rotator.php);

Will it be possible to add some jQuery code in the php so that the background image refreshes every 4 sec?

Adding a refresh in the php itself didnt work.

```
    <?php
$folder = '/home/example/public_html/wp-content/uploads/homeslider';

$extList = array();
$extList['gif'] = 'image/gif';
$extList['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg';
$extList['png'] = 'image/png';

$img = null;

if (substr($folder,-1) != '/') {
    $folder = $folder.'/';
}

if (isset($_GET['img'])) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($_GET['img']);
    if (
        isset( $extList[ strtolower( $imageInfo['extension'] ) ] ) &&
        file_exists( $folder.$imageInfo['basename'] )
    ) {
        $img = $folder.$imageInfo['basename'];
    }
} else {
    $fileList = array();
    $handle = opendir($folder);
    while ( false !== ( $file = readdir($handle) ) ) {
        $file_info = pathinfo($file);
        if (
            isset( $extList[ strtolower( $file_info['extension'] ) ] )
        ) {
            $fileList[] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    if (count($fileList) > 0) {
        $imageNumber = time() % count($fileList);
        $img = $folder.$fileList[$imageNumber];
    }
}

if ($img!=null) {
    $imageInfo = pathinfo($img);
    $contentType = 'Content-type: '.$extList[ $imageInfo['extension'] ];
    header ($contentType);
    readfile($img);
} else {
    if ( function_exists('imagecreate') ) {
        header ("Content-type: image/png");
        $im = @imagecreate (100, 100)
            or die ("Cannot initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $text_color = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
        imagestring ($im, 2, 5, 5,  "IMAGE ERROR", $text_color);
        imagepng ($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: PHP - server side, javascript(excluding nodejs) - client side. A combination of ajax and PHP (or not) can solve your problem. You can even add jquery animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the JQuery css function inside of a set interval function to change the background image every four seconds.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Changing Element Background Image with JQuery</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="target">


        </div>



        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS(Needed to make sure the element has height so the images will display):**

```
#target{   

    height:400px;

}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function($){//begin closure

//variable to keep the index count
var count = 0;


//time in milliseconds(currently set to 4 seconds)
var milliseconds = 4000;


setInterval(function(){

//selects an element with an id of target
//use .className if you want to select an element by a className
var selector = "#target";

//Array to store image urls(replace with the urls of your images)
var images= ["images/pic1.png",
             "images/pic2.jpg"];


//change the background image
$(selector).css("background-image", "url(" + images[count] +")");


//If the count is less than the image array length - 1,
//Explanation: Array indexes start at 0 so you will need to subtract
//1 to match array index. If you do not subract one then the code will
//try and load images[2] which doesn't exist.
if(count < images.length - 1){

//increment the count
count++;


}
else{

//reset count to 0 when the the last index is reached.
count = 0;


}


},milliseconds);//<-- pass in the interval time to execute the code


})(jQuery);//end closure
```

**Version with Animated Transition:**

```
(function($){//begin closure

//variable to keep the index count
var count = 0;

//Time in milliseconds(currently set to 4 seconds)for the setInterval Function
//
var milliseconds = 4000;

//Time in milliseconds for the animated transition.
var transitionTime = 1500;    

//selects an element with an id of target
//use .className if you want to select an element by a className
var selector = "#target";


setInterval(function(){



//Array to store image urls(replace with the urls of your images)
var images= ["images/pic1.png",
             "images/pic2.jpg"];


//create a new image
var tempImage = new Image();

//add the image src
tempImage.src = images[count];


//on load event for the image object
$(tempImage).on("load",function(){//begin event




//set the opacity of the element to zero(transparent),
//animate it to opaque by setting its opacity to 1
$(selector).css("opacity","0")
        .animate({ opacity: 1 }, { duration: transitionTime });

//change the background image
$(selector).css("background-image", "url(" + tempImage.src +")");


});//end event


//If the count is less than the image array length - 1,
//Explanation: Array indexes start at 0 so you will need to subtract
//1 to match array index. If you do not subract one then the code will
//try and load images[2] which doesn't exist.
if(count < images.length - 1){

//increment the count
count++;


}
else{

//reset count to 0 when the the last index is reached.
count = 0;


}


},milliseconds);//<-- pass in the interval time to execute the code


})(jQuery);//end closure
```

Comment: Dear Larry, could you break it more down, I have never worked with this before. Looks promising!, and how do i target it to a single div or class?

Comment: @T1rnanog I will update my answer with more comments around using something else besides the body tag to load a background image.

Comment: Amazing it works, only thing I don't understand yet how to i target a single div or class? for example i am using a child theme the div i like to target is called background.
BTW added this instead of count++ to make it loop
//increment the count
count = count + 1;
       if(count == images.length) 
          count = 0;

Comment: @T1rnanog I updated my answer to offer more explanation around what is going on.  You will just have to edit the selector variable to match the element for which you want to change the background. Just make sure the element has a height and width so the image will display.

Comment: Larry thank you for your time! it works perfect now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106170/discussion-between-t1rnanog-and-larry-lane).